# Format conversion not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert the format "day/month/year" to "month/day/year", i am using this code

```
string date = String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", expirydate);
```

where expiry date is 17/1/2012 but after above code nothing happens, date displays same format as it was earlier.
I have tried many time with different solutions on the web but those solutions were not successful for me.

Comment: are you sure expirydate is DateTime type?

Comment: Show more code. Hard to say what type expirydate is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your string to a `DateTime` first.

```
string expiryDate = "17/1/2012";
string date = String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", DateTime.ParseExact(expiryDate, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```